# How do I convert a JSON URL to features in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis, esri

JSON to features conversion:

I have a json url which i need imported to ArcGIS Pro and converted to Features.  How do I convert the json url to features?

I have tried using the data interoperability extension converting it to shapefile, but the imported data appears as a single row of meta data.